# For every $n>2$, the number $n!$ can be written as a sum of $n$ divisors of $n!$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

I have been thinking about the following problem:
For every $n>2$, the number $n!$ can be written as a sum of $n$ divisors of $n!$.

I think induction could be useful in this case.
For $n=3$, we get $n!=6=1+2+3$.
Now lets assume the above statement holds for $(n-1)!$, i.e. there are $d_1,...,d_{n-1}$ such that $d_1+...+d_{n-1}=(n-1)!$

If I multiply this equation by $n$, we get
$nd_1,...,nd_{n-1}=n (n-1)!$

Since $d_i$ is a divisor of $(n-1)!$ for $i=1,..,n-1$

we get that $nd_i$ is a divisor $n!$

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: What you have shown is that if $(n-1)!$ could be written as the sum of $n-1$ of its divisors, then $n!$ could also be written as the sum of $n-1$ of its divisors. It does not show that $n!$ could be written as the sum of $n$ of its divisors.

Comment: If you apply your induction step for $n=3$ you'll get $4! = 4+ 8 +12$. That's not a sum of $4$ divisors of $4!$

Comment: I have given it some thought, if write $n$ as $n=(n-1)+1$, and insert it in the the equation $nd_1+...+nd_{n-1}=n!$ I get $((n-1)+1)d_1+...+((n-1)+1)d_{n-1}=n!$ which yields $d_1+...+d_{n-1}+(n-1)(d_1+...+d_{n-1})=n!$, where both $(n-1)$ and $(d_1+...+d_{n-1})$ are divisors of $(n-1)!$.

Answer (score -2):

What you have proven is that $n!$ can be written as the sum of *three* divisors of itself, namely
$$n!=\frac{n!}{6}+\frac{n!}{3}+\frac{n!}{2}$$
True, but not very interesting!

But you can use a similar argument, with the slightly stronger inductive premise:

> For $n>2$, $n!$ can be written as a sum of $n$ divisors of $n!$, one of
> which is $1$

So we have $d_{n-1}=1$ (assumming the elements are in descending order); and multiplying this by $n$ just gives $n$, which can be expressed as $(n-1)+1$, both of whose terms are divisors of $n!$

So we get:

> $4!=4\cdot(3+2+1)=12+8+4=12+8+3+1$
> $5!=5\cdot(12+8+3+1)=60+40+15+5=60+40+15+4+1$

etc.

Comment: The OP's reasoning shows that $n-1$ divisors of $(n-1)!$ summing to $(n-1)!$ implies $n-1$ divisors of $n!$ summing to $n!$. So, technically, it only shows that $4!$ could be written as the sum of $3$ divisors of $4!$, although the proof could be modified to show that $n!$ could always be written as the sum of three divisors of $n!$ for any $n \ge 3$.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang: Yes, you are right of course.